# Refresh page when script is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use URL to remove products outside a cart.
For this I use the following HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs btn-remove-from-cart" onclick="removeItem('p','{$num}')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
```

When clicking on the button, the following script is triggered:

```
<script>
{literal}
function removeItem(type,num) {
  var response = confirm("{/literal}{$LANG.cartremoveitemconfirm}{literal}");
  if (response) {
    window.location = 'cart.php?a=remove&r='+type+'&i='+num;
  }
}
{/literal}
</script>
```

The problem is that it does work, but the results are not visable.
This because the page need to be refreshed to see that the product is removed.

Is there a way to change the script, so that the page is reloaded? Or better, that the product will be removed using AJAX, without refreshing the page?

Comment: `window.location.reload` will reload the page, however if the `cart.php` page returns no response it sounds like it's intended to be called via AJAX.

Comment: But why would you reload the whole page just to do this? This is bad design. All the css/js/html files you have to reload

Answer (score 2):

for reload page by ajax use

```
location.reload();
```

All code will looks like

```
<script>
{literal}
  function removeItem(type,num) {
    var response = confirm("{/literal}{$LANG.cartremoveitemconfirm} {literal}");
    if (response) {
      window.location = 'cart.php?a=remove&r='+type+'&i='+num;
      location.reload();
    }
  }
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but that does not work. The block/element does not reload after removing the item.

Comment: you check in your browser consul why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload the entire page without refreshing it then do this

```
jQuery(document.body).load(location.href);
```

Found a better solution here too [Partially load a div without refreshing page in javascript and php.](http://javascriptsolution.com/partially-load-a-div-without-refreshing-page-in-javascript-and-php/)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but how should I add that in my code? I tried this, but that does not work: <script>
{literal}
function removeItem(type,num) {
  var response = confirm("{/literal}{$LANG.cartremoveitemconfirm}{literal}");
  if (response) {
    window.location = 'cart.php?a=remove&r='+type+'&i='+num;
    jQuery(document.body).load(location.href);
  }
}
{/literal}
</script>